# Why can FFT (NTT?) work well on polynomial ring with some integer coefficient modulus?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I understood how FFT works over complex field $\mathbb{C}$, but still do not understand why its variant Number Theoretic Transform (NTT) works over polynomial ring with some integer coefficient modulus as well.

Does anyone have some intuitions?